# ScheduledExecutorService deals latest tasks more - why?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, scheduledexecutorservice

I've created a `ScheduledExecutorService` which is initialized to run with 30 threads.
Moreover, it is initialized with around 15 different tasks, which are supposed to run every 150-250 Milliseconds.

While running, more of these tasks were added, with same time period.

After letting the scheduler to run for 30 minutes, I saw **the latest tasks, which were added way after the first ones, were running something like 5 times more than the first tasks!**

Why? Is there a way to figure out whats happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that the first task was scheduled every 250 ms, and the last one was scheduled every 150 ms?

Comment: Yep, but I look at two tasks that have quite the same time period. And still...

Comment: How many tasks are there eventually? What's the exact method you use to schedule them?

Comment: It depends a lot on how you schedule the tasks, and how long running time the tasks have. There is a difference between .scheduleAtFixedRate and .scheduleAtFixedDelay